# How do I get multiple outputs for 2 simultaneous equations in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy, equation

I'm trying to plot a graph with 2 simultaneous equations, but I don't need to solve them, I'm just trying to get multiple results from substitution, like when x is 1, or when y is 0.

My equations are `5x + 2y = 20`, `y = 2x + 1`

All the solutions that I found are only to solve the equation, not substituting values to get multiple results.

halp pls
preferably with numpy or sympy functions, i'm tryiing to learn those haha

Answer (score 1):

expanding from the answer above from @Michael Rovinsky. since you mentioned plotting it.
I would modify the code into following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # used for ploting

def get_f1_val(x):
  return x*-2.5+10

def get_f2_val(x):
  return x*2+1

#select the value you want to use for x, you can use a for loop if theres no specific value needed, or if you need a lot of x vals for the graph
x_val = [1,2,3,4,5]
f1_y_val = []
f2_y_val = []
for xval in x_val:
  f1_y_val.append(get_f1_val(xval))
  f2_y_val.append(get_f2_val(xval))

plt.plot(x_val, f1_y_val)
plt.plot(x_val, f2_y_val)
plt.show()
```

and technically you do have to solve the equation to plot out the graph, no matter what. there isnt a way to plot something without "solving it".

Comment: Tq so much, this is actually what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two different questions: how to plot and how to get values. If you are plotting, the plotting engine will supply the values, you just have to put the equations in a form that it can work with. In this case, as univariate equations.

```
>>> from sympy import var, solve, Eq, plot
>>> var('x y')
(x, y)
>>> eqs = Eq(5*x + 2*y, 20), Eq(y, 2*x + 1)  # put into Eq form
```

Since the equations are linear in y we can use the single solution for y -- an expression in terms of x -- as the expressions to plot:

```
>>> plot(*[solve(i,y)[0] for i in eqs], (x,-1,1))
```

(Note: `plot_implicit` can plot a single equation in two variables without you having to solve for one or the other.)

Answer (score 0):

Normalize `5x + 2y = 20` to `y = -2.5x + 10` :

```
def get_values(x):
  return [x * -2.5 + 10, x * 2 + 1]

print(get_values(-1))
print(get_values(0))
print(get_values(1))
```